# How to handle the OpenCV(4.5.3)

Tags: python, opencv

We are implementing the code for brain tumor classification using Support Vector Machine (SVM). But the error arises by running the final block of code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
c=1
for i in os.listdir('./data/Training'):
    plt.subplot(4,4,c)
    img  = cv2.imread('./data/Training'+i,0)
    img1 = cv2.resize(img, (200,200))
    img1 = img1.reshape(1 ,-1)/255
    p = sv.predict(img)
    plt.title(dec[p[0]])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.axis('off')
    c+=1
```

[image]

Comment: Stop Using Image
Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: You might consider using `pathlib` rather than `os`.  Do you need another `/`?  For example, `img  = cv2.imread('./data/Training/'+i,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the os.listdir `./data/Training/` where I consider retrieving all of the data from the dataset and trying to display with tumor exist and the tumor does not exist. Which is not possible. So for solving the problem, I used the following os.listdir`./data/Training/no_tumor/` and now it will give me a result, by determining which image contains the tumor and which one does not.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
p = os.listdir('./data/Training/')

c=1
for i in os.listdir('./data/Training/no_tumor/')[:16]:
    plt.subplot(4,4,c)
    img  = cv2.imread('./data/Training/no_tumor/'+i,0)
    img1 = cv2.resize(img, (200,200))
    img1 = img1.reshape(1 ,-1)/255
    p = sv.predict(img1)

    plt.title(dec['no_tumor'])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.axis('off')
    c+=1
```

[image: Here is the output of the given code]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the provided directory.

1. Initialize the main parent directory from where all the images are taken.

```
os.listdir('./data/Training):
```

2. Now the user has the option to get the specific type of tumor image from the directory.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
c=1
for i in os.listdir('./data/Training/no_Tumor/'):
    plt.subplot(4,4,c)
    img  = cv2.imread('./data/Training/no_Tumor/'+i,0)
    img1 = cv2.resize(img, (200,200))
    img1 = img1.reshape(1 ,-1)/255
    p = sv.predict(img)
    plt.title(dec[p[0]])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.axis('off')
    c+=1
```